# Desktop freeze, Gnome failure

Tags: gnome, crash

On a Macbook pro early 2011, I have Ubuntu 21.10 (64-bit X11 Gnome 40.4.0)

```
mac2011-linux% snap list|grep gnome
gnome-3-28-1804          3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  161    latest/stable    canonical*    -
gnome-3-34-1804          0+git.3556cb3               72     latest/stable/…  canonical*    -
gnome-3-38-2004          0+git.6ba6040               76     latest/stable    canonical*    -
```

but I have observed the problem before with Ubuntu 21.04: once a day or so, the desktop freezes, only the mouse moves but nothing else responds.

Workaround: `ssh` into my session from another machine and `killall -u me`.  I believe this shows it is a problem with Gnome only.

I think I have tracked the crash in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Oct 25 11:18:36 mac2011-linux gnome-shell[2804]: pushModal: invocation of begin_modal failed
Oct 25 11:18:46 mac2011-linux gnome-shell[2804]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Oct 25 11:18:46 mac2011-linux gnome-shell[2804]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Oct 25 11:18:46 mac2011-linux gnome-shell[2804]: Object .GUnionVolumeMonitor (0x7f309801c6c0), has been already deallocated — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
Oct 25 11:18:46 mac2011-linux gnome-shell[2804]: == Stack trace for context 0x557fe561b130 ==
Oct 25 11:18:46 mac2011-linux gnome-shell[2804]: #0   557feaff2a48 i   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/GObject.js:567 (2343745b1d80 @ 25)
Oct 25 11:18:46 mac2011-linux gnome-shell[2804]: #1   557feaff29b0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/components/autorunManager.js:159 (3f6d4d8693d0 @ 31)
Oct 25 11:18:46 mac2011-linux gnome-shell[2804]: #2   557feaff2918 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/components/__init__.js:56 (35eb7dada6a0 @ 66)
Oct 25 11:18:46 mac2011-linux gnome-shell[2804]: #3   557feaff2888 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/components/__init__.js:22 (35eb7dada7e0 @ 15)
Oct 25 11:18:46 mac2011-linux gnome-shell[2804]: #4   7ffdd3dcd830 b   self-hosted:225 (35eb7da2aa10 @ 273)
Oct 25 11:18:46 mac2011-linux gnome-shell[2804]: #5   557feaff27f8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/components/__init__.js:22 (35eb7dada920 @ 110)
Oct 25 11:18:46 mac2011-linux gnome-shell[2804]: #6   7ffdd3dce490 b   self-hosted:850 (35eb7da2a650 @ 423)
Oct 25 11:18:46 mac2011-linux gnome-shell[2804]: #7   7ffdd3dce580 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/_signals.js:114 (2343745b1330 @ 439)
Oct 25 11:18:46 mac2011-linux gnome-shell[2804]: #8   7ffdd3dced70 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/sessionMode.js:200 (19dd8bfe6d30 @ 284)
Oct 25 11:18:46 mac2011-linux gnome-shell[2804]: #9   557feaff2698 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/sessionMode.js:161 (19dd8bfe6e70 @ 40)
Oct 25 11:18:46 mac2011-linux gnome-shell[2804]: #10   557feaff25e0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/screenShield.js:646 (19dd8bfd4970 @ 208)
Oct 25 11:18:46 mac2011-linux gnome-shell[2804]: #11   557feaff2518 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/screenShield.js:690 (19dd8bfd4920 @ 343)
Oct 25 11:18:46 mac2011-linux gnome-shell[2804]: #12   557feaff2488 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/screenShield.js:327 (19dd8bfdc290 @ 25)
```

Can you confirm the problem?  Do you have a better solution?  Should I report a Gnome bug?

Comment: I have observed once that the keyboard and the buttons in the Firefox window also work and that normal functions recover after a few minutes.

Comment: Now I realize that my Gnome is a snap so maybe I should reinstall with apt.  Afraid of breaking everything though.

Comment: The snap part only contains some libraries and data, not everything, and that should only be used by other snap-installed components, not your session manager. You should already have the APT package `ubuntu-session` installed, which is the Canonical-modified Gnome session manager that's installed by default on Ubuntu nowadays.

Comment: Concerning the SSH login, it shouldn't be necessary in this case, just switch to another virtual console (VC). On PC keyboards, the shortcut is Ctrl + Alt + Fn, Fn being one of the function keys F1, F2, F3 etc. On Apple keyboards, I guess something around the lines Ctrl + Command (i.e. Apple icon) + Fn. F1 brings you to VC1 (tty1), F2 to VC2 (tty2) and so on. VC1 is used for the graphical login screen, so I advise you better go to, say, VC2, 3 or 4. You will then see a terminal login prompt where you can login locally, and perform the same things you were doing through SSH.